# How can I choose hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv value

Tags: stm32, c, stm32cubemx, keil

I am using STM32L073V8T6 microchip. I'm trying to get clock data using RTC with this.

If I set the hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv value to 258 while configuring, it overcounts about 4 minutes in 24 hours. Even if I choose 259, it lags 3-4 minutes in 24 hours. Values less than 258 count more, values over count less. What to do in this situation

Comment: What are the other values in your RTC initialisation?  You might find this [ST forum post](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000j5I4aSAE/how-set-up-pretty-presice-and-detailed-rtc-on-stm32h743zi2) helpful.

Comment: hrtc.Instance = RTC;
hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = 127;
hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = 255;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutRemap = RTC_OUTPUT_REMAP_NONE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutType = RTC_OUTPUT_TYPE_OPENDRAIN;

Comment: What is your clock source?

Comment: I use crystal resonator

Answer (score 0):

When the basic clock source isn't accurate enough on its own, you have to either **calibrate** it or periodically **correct** it.

The [ST Application Note 4759: Using the hardware RTC](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an4759-using-the-hardware-realtime-clock-rtc-and-the-tamper-management-unit-tamp-with-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf) covers all of the material.

You appear to have the prescalers set for a 32,768 Hz clock.  Is your source that accurate?

[image]

**Scaling**

If your current settings are too fast, you can experiment with other values.  For example you are too fast by 4 / 24 * 60) ≈ 0.3%

So instead of (127 + 1) * (258 + 1) = 33152, find numbers which multiply to 33152 - 0.3%, perhaps 33060, which is 60 * 551.

**Better Methods**

Have a look at the "Smooth Digital Calibration" and "Synchronization" sections of the Application Note.